# My output is skipping a few phrases that I inputed

Tags: java, alphabetical

I am supposed to take an input of names and output it sorted in order using compareTo function. But it is skipping words when I input a lot of strings. Anyone know why?

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter the names and designate the end with a -1:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String person = in.next();

    if (names.isEmpty())
    {
        names.add(person);
        person = in.next();
    }

    while (!person.equals("-1"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        {
            String nameInList = names.get(i);
            if (nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person) > 0)
            {
                names.add(i, person);
                break;
            }
        }
        person = in.next();
    }
    System.out.println(names);
}

}
```

Comment: `if (nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person) > 0)` ... what happens when it's not?

Comment: if it's not doesn't it update the index already to check with the next word in the list?

Comment: What happens if `nameInList` < `person`?  When does `person` get added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

You are not dealing with the case where the person name you entered is smaller than the names already present in your list:

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        String nameInList = names.get(i);
        if (nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person) > 0)
        {
            names.add(i, person);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) names.add(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

Add all elements to list first until `-1` is entered. The `Sort` at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        String person = "";
        System.out.println("Enter the names and designate the end with a -1:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            person = in.next();
             if(!person.equals("-1")){
                 names.add(person);
             }else{
                 break;
             }
        }

        Collections.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(names);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Enter the names and designate the end with a -1:
ankur
singhal
-1
[ankur, singhal]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider for a moment, the following input...

```
Jane
Adam
Harry
Potter
```

- `Jane` > `Adam` (`9`), so `Adam` is add at position 0
- `Harry` < `Adam` (`-7`), but > `Jane` (`2`), `Harry` is added to position `1`
- `Admin` < `Potter` (`-15`), < `Harry` (`-8`), < `Jane` (`-6`) and is therefore completely ignored and never added to the list

So our final list looks like...

```
[Adam, Harry, Jane]
```

Let's change the code slightly, to something more like...

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Enter the names and designate the end with a -1:");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String person = "-1";
do {
    person = in.nextLine();
    if (!person.equals("-1")) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < names.size(); i++) {
            String nameInList = names.get(i);
            System.out.println(" > " + nameInList + " = " + nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person));
            if (nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person) > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Added @ " + i);
        names.add(i, person);
    }
} while (!person.equals("-1"));
System.out.println(names);
```

With the same input, we get

```
[Adam, Harry, Jane, Potter]
```

as the output.

This is because we've setup the `for-loop` to find the best possible position for the given name.  If, at any stage `nameInList` is > `person`, then the loop breaks and we use the current value of `i` as the insert point, otherwise, `i` becomes the next position in the list (which is a nice side affect of the `add` method)

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < names.size(); i++) {
    String nameInList = names.get(i);
    System.out.println(" > " + nameInList + " = " + nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person));
    if (nameInList.compareToIgnoreCase(person) > 0) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Added @ " + i);
// Every body is added in the end!
names.add(i, person);
```

Now, because the list is sorted, we could use a binary search to find the proposed placement for the string, but that might be a bit beyond the requirements ;)